# How to change orientation of a SCNNode to the Camera with ARKit

Tags: ios, arkit, xcode9, scnnode

The code below places a SCNPlane onto the point touched, but the plane is oriented (rotated) to the position that the phone was in when the app started.  I would ideally like to orient the Node to a physical wall or to the current orientation of the camera.  How is this done with ARKit?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else {return}
    let result = sceneView.hitTest(touch.location(in: sceneView), types: [ARHitTestResult.ResultType.featurePoint])
    guard let hitResult = result.last else {return}
    let hitTransform = SCNMatrix4.init(hitResult.worldTransform)

    let hitVector = SCNVector3Make(hitTransform.m41, hitTransform.m42, hitTransform.m43)
    createPlane(position: hitVector)
}

func createPlane(position: SCNVector3) {

    let background = SCNNode()
    background.geometry = SCNPlane.init(width: 0.12, height: 0.10) // better set its size
    background.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = "odinBW2.jpeg"
    background.position = position

    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(background)

}
```

Comment: did you find any solution for it??

Comment: In the end I decided to prepare the user with instructions to face the phone in the proper direction before starting the arkit view.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to align your node to the camera's orientation, just use [SCNBillboardConstraint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnbillboardconstraint).

```
let yourNode = SCNNode()

let billboardConstraint = SCNBillboardConstraint()
billboardConstraint.freeAxes = [.X, .Y, .Z]
yourNode.constraints = [billboardConstraint]
```

Comment: This is pretty awesome. Thanks!

Comment: `billboardConstraint.freeAxes = [.X, .Y, .Z]` is redundant, that's the default (`SCNBillboardAxis.all`). Can just do  `yourNode.constraints = [SCNBillboardConstraint()]`

Answer (score 7):

1 - This is how you get the rotation of the camera first:

> Pitch - rotation around the X axis

```
let pitch = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.x
```

> Yawn - rotation around the Y axis

```
let yawn = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.y
```

> Roll - rotation around the Z axis

```
let roll = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.z
```

2 - And then you can create the SCNVector3 that matches the rotations you want to keep (0 if you don't want any rotation on an axis) :

```
let newRotation = SCNVector3Make(pitch, yawn, roll)
```

3 - And then you attribute this eulerAngles to your node:

```
whateverNode.eulerAngles = newRotation
```

Comment: This works great when the phone is in landscape mode, but not portrait.

Comment: @Alan_s This works for landscape and portrait, I think you locked your AR to landscape that's why.

Comment: Is this a setting on ARSceneView or something similar?

Comment: not work for me in portrait.
What you mean by " locked your AR to landscape"